# sql self compare with the word ALL

Tags: sql

can sombody help me understand the process behind this code? (what will happen in every step of the "where" conditions)

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world x
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world y
        WHERE y.continent=x.continent
          AND area>0)
```

why exactly it will give me the country with the biggest area in every continent ...
thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are :

- selecting `continent, name, area` from `world`.
- comparing `area` to make sure it's bigger than or equal to `ALL(/*items in subquery*/)`.
- making a subquery which selects all areas from the same continent.
- in essence you are comparing an `area` with `ALL(/*other areas on the same continent*/)`.